# Saving a video from a view in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-videoview

Basically, I need to figure out how to save a video file of a certain duration from a View.

I'm working on a collage program. I want to be able to add images and videos to a view, which I've figured out for the most part, and then save the View (like a constraint layout) to a video file. I thought about screen recording an area of the screen, but I feel like there are better ways to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is part of the Flutter wiki, [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Making-animated-GIFs-of-Flutter-apps) has some good information on recording videos on Android.

While you are running your Android app, you can run `adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/recording.mp4` on the command line to record the video and stop the recording with CTRL+c.

The video can then be pulled off the device with: `adb pull /sdcard/recording.mp4 ~/Downloads/`.